# Creating a custom reduce function with crossfilter and dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to create a rowchart in dc.js which displays the count of a person divided by the hours they worked on a given date.
My data is organized as follows:

```
Person    Hours  Date
Joe       3      1-2-16
Joe       3      1-2-16
Devon     5      1-2-16
Devon     5      1-2-16
Joe       4      1-3-16
Devon     1      1-3-16
Devon     1      1-3-16
```

How do I create a custom reduce function which can sum the count of the Person column (reduceCount) and divide it by the value of Hours for a specific date range? A given person has a set number of Hours on a given Date. So for example if I filter the data for all dates I want to return:

```
Joe   0.4286
Devon 0.6666
```

Which comes from total counts of Joe (3) divided by Hours Joe worked (7). Devon would be 4 divided by 6.

Filtering only the date 1-2-16, I would like to return:

```
Joe   0.6666
Devon 0.2
```

Which comes from total counts of Joe (2)  divided by Hours Joe worked (3).
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about why your data is set up like this? If you don't have an external need to have your data in this exact format, I'd just say you should pre-process your data so that each person just has one record per day with an additional dimension for "count". Then just divide `count/hours`.

Comment: This seems like the best approach, but what is the syntax for creating the crossfilter group for sum(count)/sum(hours)?

Comment: Lots of examples of custom reduce functions in the dc.js FAQ - https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/faq I'd suggest taking a shot at it and then updating the question with a code sample (or better, a working example on JSFiddle or Codepen).

Comment: IIUC is just the usual average calculation like the first question in the FAQ but instead of sum / count you want count / sum.